# Deploy a flexdashboard on github

Tags: r, github, shiny, flexdashboard

### Problem context

I am trying to deploy a flexdashboard to github to share the link with other people. I have tried [this](https://github.com/pbatey/flexdashboard-example) but when I use `rmarkdown::render()` or `rmarkdown::render_site()` I have this error in the console:

```
Error: path for html_dependency not provided
```

When I try [this](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2020/09/deploying-flexdashboard-on-github-pages/) the console shows `Output created: C:/Users/danie/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpum47SE/file1604424c59ee.html` and the `.html` file isn't in "docs" folder.

### Code

I have two scripts: `.yml` and `.Rmd`; the data is in the working directory.

#### .yml

```
name: "dashboardEco"
output_file: "docs"
```

#### .Rmd

````
---
title: "Homicidios (1993-2019)"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: fill
    theme: bootstrap
    #social: menu
    
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(readxl)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(scales)
library(shiny)

#funciones####
read_excel_allsheets <- function(filename, tibble = FALSE) {
  # I prefer straight data.frames
  # but if you like tidyverse tibbles (the default with read_excel)
  # then just pass tibble = TRUE
  sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(filename)
  x <- lapply(sheets, function(X) readxl::read_excel(filename, sheet = X))
  if(!tibble) x <- lapply(x, as.data.frame)
  names(x) <- sheets
  x
} #leer todos los sheets de un excell y guarfarlos en una lista

gr_edad<-function(data){
  data$g_edad<-ifelse(data$EDAD < 10, "0  a 9 años",
                      ifelse(data$EDAD > 9 & data$EDAD < 20, "10 a 19 años",
                             ifelse(data$EDAD > 19 & data$EDAD < 30, "20 a 29 años",
                                    ifelse(data$EDAD > 29 & data$EDAD < 40, "30 a 39 años",
                                           ifelse(data$EDAD > 39 & data$EDAD < 50, "40 a 49 años",
                                                  ifelse(data$EDAD > 49 & data$EDAD < 60, "50 a 59 años",
                                                         ifelse(data$EDAD > 59 & data$EDAD < 70, "60 a 69 años",
                                                                ifelse(data$EDAD > 69 & data$EDAD < 80, "70 a 79 años",
                                                                       ifelse(data$EDAD > 79 & data$EDAD < 90, "80 a 89 años",
                                                                              ifelse(data$EDAD > 89 & data$EDAD < 100, "90 a 99 años",
                                                                                     ifelse(data$EDAD > 99, "100 años en adelante","sin grupo")))))))))))
  return(data)
}

sum_byage_c<-function(data){
  
  df<-data.frame()
  edades<-unique(data$g_edad)
  
  for (edad in edades){
    data_<-subset(data,data$g_edad == edad)
    data_<-data_%>%group_by(fechao,categoria_movil) %>% summarise(Freq=n())
    data_$g_edad<-edad
    df<-rbind(df,data_)
  }
  
  return(df)
  
}

sum_byage_sc<-function(data){
  
  df<-data.frame()
  
  for (edad in unique(data$g_edad)){
    data_<-subset(data,data$g_edad == edad)
    data_<-data_%>%group_by(fechao,subcategoria_movil) %>% summarise(Freq=n())
    data_$g_edad<-edad
    df<-rbind(df,data_)
  }
  
  return(df)
  
}

comunas_tipoV<-function(data){
  
  df<-data.frame()
  comunas<-unique(data$com)
  
  for (comuna in comunas){
    data_<-subset(data,data$com == comuna)
    data_<-data_%>%group_by(fechao,tipo_violencia) %>% summarise(Freq=n())
    data_$com<-comuna
    df<-rbind(df,data_)
  }
  
  return(df)
  
}



#procesamiento####
homicidios<-read_excel_allsheets("DATOS_1993-2019.xlsx")
homicidios<-homicidios[[2]]

homicidios$EDAD[is.na(homicidios$EDAD)]<-200

homicidios<-gr_edad(homicidios)





```

Column {.sidebar}
=======================================================================

###

```{r}
selectInput(inputId = "Edad_", 
            label = "Edad",
            choices = unique(homicidios$g_edad))
            #choices = genero,
            #selected = "Total")

selectInput(inputId = "Mov_", 
            label = "Movil", 
            choices = unique(homicidios$categoria_movil))
            #selected = "1993")

selectInput(inputId = "sMov_", 
            label = "sMovil", 
            choices = unique(homicidios$subcategoria_movil))
            #selected = "1993")

selectInput(inputId = "Com_", 
            label = "Com", 
            choices = unique(homicidios$com))
            #selected = "1993")

selectInput(inputId = "tipo_", 
            label = "Tipo", 
            choices = unique(homicidios$tipo_violencia))
            #selected = "1993")


```


-----------------------------------------------------------------------

Categoría móvil, grupos de edad
=======================================================================

row {data-width=350}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Móvil
```{r}

movil_<-homicidios[,c(8,11,16,18)]
movil_m<-subset(movil_,movil_$SEXO == "M")
movil_f<-subset(movil_,movil_$SEXO == "F")
#
movil_m<-sum_byage_c(movil_m)
movil_m$SEXO<-"M"
#
movil_f<-sum_byage_c(movil_f)
movil_f$SEXO<-"F"
#

#
#
movil<-rbind(movil_f,movil_m)
#
movil_r <- reactive({
  movil[movil$g_edad == input$Edad_ & movil$categoria_movil == input$Mov_, c(1,3,5)]
    })
#
#
renderPlotly({

  movil <- movil_r()

  cmov<-ggplot(data=movil, aes(fill=SEXO,x=fechao, y=Freq)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge",stat="identity")+
    xlab("")+
    ylab("")+
  theme_classic()+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_x_continuous("Año",labels=as.character(movil$fechao),breaks = movil$fechao)

  ggplotly(cmov)

})


```

row {data-width=350}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Sub-móvil
```{r}

smovil_<-homicidios[,c(8,11,17,18)]
smovil_m<-subset(smovil_,smovil_$SEXO == "M")
smovil_f<-subset(smovil_,smovil_$SEXO == "F")
#
smovil_m<-sum_byage_sc(smovil_m)
smovil_m$SEXO<-"M"
#
smovil_f<-sum_byage_sc(smovil_f)
smovil_f$SEXO<-"F"
#

#
#
smovil<-rbind(smovil_f,smovil_m)
#
smovil_r <- reactive({
  smovil[smovil$g_edad == input$Edad_ & smovil$subcategoria_movil == input$sMov_, c(1,3,5)]
    })
#
#
renderPlotly({

  smovil <- smovil_r()

  smov<-ggplot(data=smovil, aes(fill=SEXO,x=fechao, y=Freq)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge",stat="identity")+
    xlab("")+
    ylab("")+
  theme_classic()+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_x_continuous("Año",labels=as.character(smovil$fechao),breaks = smovil$fechao)

  ggplotly(smov)

})

```

-----------------------------------------------------------------------

Tipo violencia, comunas
=======================================================================

row {data-width=350}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Distribución Comunas - Tipo violencia
```{r}
#

homicidios$com[homicidios$com > 22]<-23

tipo_<-homicidios%>%group_by(com,tipo_violencia) %>% summarise(Freq=n())

#
#tipo_r <- reactive({
#  tipo_[tipo_$com == input$Com_, c(1:3)]
#    })
#
#
renderPlotly({

  #tipo <- tipo_r()

  tipov<-ggplot(data=tipo_, aes(fill=tipo_violencia,x=com, y=Freq)) +
  geom_bar(position="stack",stat="identity")+
    xlab("")+
    ylab("")+
  theme_classic()+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5))+
  scale_x_continuous("Comuna",labels=as.character(tipo_$com),breaks = tipo_$com)

  ggplotly(tipov)

})


```


row {data-width=350}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Tipo violencia por comuna
```{r}
#
tipo_<-comunas_tipoV(homicidios)


#
tipo_r <- reactive({
  tipo_[tipo_$com == input$Com_, c(1:3)]
    })
#
#
renderPlotly({

  tipo <- tipo_r()

  tipov<-ggplot(data=tipo, aes(fill=tipo_violencia,x=fechao, y=Freq)) +
  geom_bar(position="stack",stat="identity")+
    xlab("")+
    ylab("")+
  theme_classic()+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_x_continuous("Año",labels=as.character(tipo$fechao),breaks = tipo$fechao)

  ggplotly(tipov)

})


```
````

#### Final comments

- I uninstall R and R studio and delete all the packages and install it again.
- When I use `rmarkdown::run()` just deploy the flexdashboard on local host.

Any idea how can I deploy it on github? or solve the problem?

Comment: I think the problem is that you are using `runtime: shiny` which needs an R process to support it which I guess you don't have for github pages. Also, your second link states that RMD + shiny doesn't work for github pages.

Answer (score 2):

Like stated above, since you are using Shiny, you can either host your own Shiny server on the internet, OR you can use [shinyapps.io](https://www.shinyapps.io/) to deploy and host your shiny app for free, as long as it doesn't get a lot of traffic. Rstudio makes this very easy to publish. You can then create a *github pages* webpage and redirect it to your shiny app and still backup the code on github too.

[image]